# In VSCode how to put all the c files into args?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

When i try to build this code, i get the " undefined reference to 'square' " error because it doesnt put the square.c and cube.c into the build command:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "square.h"
#include "cube.h"

#define cube(x) (x*x*x)

int main(void) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 30; ++i)
    printf("%4d %10d %10d\n", i, square(i), cube(i));
  return 0;
 }
```

My task.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "-ansi",
                "-pedantic",
                "-Wall",
                "-W",
                "${relativeFile}",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

All the required files are in the same folder, and im on linux.
How can i make it build all the required files automatically?

Comment: Learn how to compile executables in the command line before using an external build system (vscode).

Comment: Then put the files in your build command?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following strings to the `"args"` array:

`"square.c"`,
`"cube.c"`, resulting in the following array:

```
"args": [
        "-ansi",
        "-pedantic",
        "-Wall",
        "-W",
        "${relativeFile}",
        "square.c",
        "cube.c"
        "-o",
        "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"
],
```